# My candy box 2 game doesn't save, and it has an error message in the 'save menu.'

Tags: candy-box-2

When I closed out candy box 2, the game didn't save, and when I went to the save slot websites, they were all empty, and nothing I did worked. In the save menu, it says "Your browser does not seem to support HTML5. (local storage and application cache) You should update your browser in order to use the local saving feature." My browser is fully updated, and I am able to save all the other games I play. I am on chrome and I have cookies and javascript enabled. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: 1) What browser do you have? 2) Do you have javascript enabled? 3) Do you have cookies enabled?

Comment: @Penguin I have chrome, and I have both of those enabled.

Comment: does going to `chrome://settings/help` do anything (it might not im on edge so i dont know but just try it, its how i updated mine) also it doesnt seem to want to be a link so its in code format sorry

Comment: @Penguin my Chrome is fully updated, and there is nothing else there to do other than to update it.